# how to use serial communication to change the slides of powerpoint presentation?

Tags: automation, serial-port, arduino, slideshow, powerpoint

I have an arduino uno kit. I 'll be giving it signals .These signals should be able to navigate the slides of powerpoint. Also these signals will be coming thru the serial port . 
hence is there any software which allows me directly to do the required slide change ?Or should i be writing a code for the same ? If so in which language as iam quite new to this type of stuffs!

Answer (score 1):

This is basically the same question as this one: [What is the best way to access a serial port from VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569698/what-is-the-best-way-to-access-a-serial-port-from-vba)

The answer refers to here: http://www.thescarms.com/vbasic/commio.aspx

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to have the arduino emulate the serial mouse protocol and send mouse clicks for the Powerpoint navigation (just like pressing the mouse button to go to the next or previous slide).  The problem is that as far as I know there are no serial mouse emulation libraries for Arduino, but I could be wrong.

Another option would be use use the [LUFA](http://www.fourwalledcubicle.com/LUFA.php) USB library to have your UNO emulate a USB mouse.  The problem with this option is that while LUFA is compatible with the UNO hardware, you need to reflash the firmware.  And I believe you can't program it with the arduino IDE.

The easiest option would be to not use the UNO but get a [Leonardo](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardLeonardo) or a [Teensy](http://www.pjrc.com/store/teensy.html) both can act as a USB Mouse device and can be programmed with the Arduino IDE.

Answer (score 1):

The hardest part would be reading the serial data coming in and ensuring that it's valid.  Then, depending on what command you receive (next slide, previous slide, etc.), send [simulated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) mouse clicks or keyboard presses to PowerPoint. Better yet, you could just use the [PowerPoint COM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.aspx) interface.